# sum hits for every week in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I have a table with number of page views per day. Something like this:

```
+------+------------+------+----------+
|  id  | date       | hits | mangaID  |
+------+------------+------+----------+
| 4876 | 1331843400 | 132  |    13    |
+------+------------+------+----------+
| 4876 | 1331929800 | 24   |    236   |
+------+------------+------+----------+
| 7653 | 1331929800 | 324  |    13    |
+------+------------+------+----------+
```

I'm trying to get sum hits from last week with the below code:

```
SELECT sum(hits) as hits FROM om_manga_views WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 week) <= date and mangaID = '13'
```

My problem is that I'm storing date as time using `strtotime` in date's field as int type.

So how can i get what i want!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(hits) hitCount from t
where from_unixtime(date) >= current_date() - interval 1 week and mangaId = 11
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06a7c/2) to play with.

I slightly changed your data because the records you provided are older than 7 days, so the `sum` would return `0`.